# Access denied issue in Devops build pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

While am trying to run the Azure build pipeline, am facing the following error and pipeline fails at the initial stage.

"One or more errors occurred. (Access to the path 'c:\Agents\Agent-02_work\1\s\out\Release\bin\TimeZoneCalc.dll' is denied."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk8P1.png)

PLease help me with the solution. why this error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it may cause by the permission denied to access the file.

Since you are using the self-hosted agent, you could try to use the **administrator account** (Local system admin) to create and run the agent.

For interactive mode self-hosted agent:

You could use the following command to create an agent with admin account.

```
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsAutoLogon --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\adminaccount --windowsLogonPassword Password
```